# How to Convert a String to bits in C#

Tags: c#, string, encryption

I am working on a project that ciphers a text using Position Swapping. I've completed the project using char  position swapping { Hello -> elloH}, now i am working on bit position swapping. I am using the same algorithm to cipher the bits but the problem is how to change the resulting bits back to a string ?

**Note:BitArray is not possible to be used.**

Here is what i've got now :

```
static byte[] toByteArray(string s)
    {
        byte[] arr = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(s);
        return arr;
    }// Byte Array must be changed to bits.
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String[] X = new String[x.Length];// Will Contain the Encoded Bits
        for(int i=0;i<x.Length;i++)
        {
            X[i] = Convert.ToString(x[i], 2);
            textBox3.Text += X[i];
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to shift bits only within a byte or also between bytes? Why cant you use a BitArray? Beware that changing (more or less) random bits in a byte may make it impossible to render this byte as a character in a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        string str = "1000111"; //this is your string in bits
        byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length / 7];
        int j = 0;
        while (str.Length > 0)
        {
            var result = Convert.ToByte(str.Substring(0, 7), 2);
            bytes[j++] = result;
            if (str.Length >= 7)
                str = str.Substring(7);
        }
        var resultString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: you're very welcome. Could you please upvote my answer as well?